# Make all line graphs grey using grey scale, apart from one coloured line in Seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn, visualization, linegraph

I need to colour all line graphs in a different grey, using one of Seaborn's greyscale, like binary. One line (2022), however, needs to be orange.

This is what I currently have:
[image]

This is what my code looks like, I have not been able to get a grey colour palette to work in there:

```
palette = {year:'orange' if year == 2022 else 'gray' for year in df.year.unique()}

sns.set(rc = {'figure.figsize':(12, 8)})
ax = sns.lineplot(x = 'week' 
                  , y = 'Deduplication Ratio' 
                  , hue = 'year' 
                  , ci = None
                  , data = df
                  , palette = palette
                  )
```

I would like the data to look like this though:
[Excel data viz with 1 orange line, and 3 lines in different greys.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJdAs.jpg)

Would anyone know how I can display the grey lines in different greys?

PS: I have to replicate this task multiple times where there will be more than just 4 years. So doing this manually will not be an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
years = sorted(df["year"].unique())
greys = iter(sns.color_palette("Greys", len(years)))
palette = {year: 'orange' if year == 2022 else next(greys) for year in years}
```

Comment: This worked a charm, thanks so much, @mwaskom.

The slide already looks much clearer. 

Would you know how I could make the orange (only) line bold?

Comment: Same idea but with `size` and `sizes`.

Comment: I didn't get it to work, unfortunately. 

Would that be smth like this?

`size_df = iter(sns.color_palette("binary", len(years)))
sizes = {year: 10 if year == 2022 else next(size_df) for year in years}`


and then do 


`sns.lineplot(… 
                  , linewidth = sizes
)`